What is correct and what is wrong in the derivative of the composition of two functions?
Let :$f(x,y)=f(u,v)$
In the lecture at my university :
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2}\left({\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}\right)^2+2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u\partial v}\left({\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}\right)+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2}\left({\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}\right)^2+\color{red}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \left({\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}}\right)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \left({\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}}\right)}$$
I think this is wrong because :
We have :
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
Therfore:
\begin{align*}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}&=\left({\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}\right)\left({\frac{\partial }{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial }{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}\right)\\ &= \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2}\left({\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}\right)^2+2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u\partial v}\left({\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}\right)+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2}\left({\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}\right)^2\end{align*}
Is the professor wrong or is there something I didn't notice?

$
\def\pt{{\partial}}
$
You seem to be interpreting $\partial^2 f /\partial x^2$ as something like $(\pt f/\pt x)^2$. This is not correct — that you got close to the correct answer is sort of a coincidence. To obtain the correct answer, you need to differentiate the chain rule expression you have given; that is,
\begin{align}
\frac{\pt^2 f}{\pt x^2} &= \frac{\pt}{\pt x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)
\\
&= \frac{\pt}{\pt x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial^ 2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\pt}{\pt x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right)\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial^ 2 v}{\partial x^2} \tag{1} \label{eqn}
\end{align}
Now, $\pt f/\pt u$ must be differentiated using the multivariable chain rule, just like for $f$, which gives
$$
\frac{\pt}{\pt x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right)=
\frac{\partial^ 2 f}{\partial u^2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^ 2 f}{\pt u \partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.
$$
You can obtain a similar expression for $\frac{\pt}{\pt x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right) $ in the same way. Substituting these two expressions into \eqref{eqn} should yield the expression given by your professor.
